# How to compute $\sum_{k =1}^{100}(-1)^k$

Tags: summation

Today I tried to compute $$ \sum_{k =1}^{100}(-1)^k $$

**Is there a way to find the result more quickly ?**

Below if my attempt to find the result.

Especially without considering the case of odd and even numbers like I did ?

---

Let's consider the following sum:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k = (-1)^1 + (-1)^2 + (-1)^3 + ...  +(-1)^n $$

If $n$ is even then $\frac n2 $ terms have an even exponent and $\frac n2 $ terms have an odd exponent.

$$(-1)^p = -1   \tag{when $p$ is odd}   $$
$$ (-1)^p = 1  \tag{when $p$ is even}
$$

Then when $n$ is even

$$\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k &= \frac n2 \times(-1) +   \frac n2 \times 1  \\
  & =  \frac n2  - \frac n2 \\  
  & =   0 \\ 
\end{align}$$

100 is an even number, so

$$ \sum_{k =1}^{100}(-1)^k = 0 $$

Comment: Call the sum $S$, so that $S=(-1)+(1)+\dotsb+(-1)+(1)$. Notice that $-S=(1)+(-1)+\dotsb+(1)+(-1)$—that is, $-S$ is just $S$ reversed. So, $S=-S$, which means that $S=0$.

Comment: If you say that $n/2$ terms have an even exponent, then you are already assuming that $n$ is even.

Comment: The quick way is to cancel $1$s with $-1$s.  You have equally many of both, and if you didn't, you'd have just one term left after canceling.  But of course it's also a finite geometric series, and there's a standard formula for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the series has a direct summation formula: 
$$
S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i={1 \over 2}\Big((-1)^k-1\Big)
$$
you can prove this easily using induction.
$$\begin{aligned}
\mbox{k=1: }\ \ \ &true\\
\mbox{k }\to\mbox{ k+1: }\ \ \ &S_{k+1}=S_{k}+(-1)^{k+1}&={1 \over 2}\Big((-1)^k-1\Big)+(-1)^{k+1} =\\
& &={1 \over 2}\Big((-1)^k+2(-1)^{k+1}-1\Big) =\\
& &={1 \over 2}\Big((-1)^k(1+2(-1)^{1})-1\Big) =\\
& &={1 \over 2}\Big((-1)^k(1-2)-1\Big) =\\
& &={1 \over 2}\Big((-1)^k(-1)-1\Big) =\\
& &={1 \over 2}\Big((-1)^{k+1}-1\Big) \ \ \ \square
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $(-1)^{2k-1}=-1$ and $(-1)^{2k}=1$ for all $k\geq1$. Hence the sum upto any even power should equal $0$.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to *find* the result is to look at the first few partial sums

$$ -1, 0, -1, \ldots $$

and identify the pattern. Everything beyond that is just seeking to give a more rigorous justification of it.

Comment: Sure. I think that's what I am looking for. A rigorous justification but explained quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(-1)^{2n}=1$ and $(-1)^{2n-1}=-1$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k = -1+1-1+1-\cdots \pm 1=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}-1 & \text{if}\,n\,\text{is odd}\\
0 & \text{if}\,n\,\text{is even}\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)(-1)^{k-1}=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}=$$
$$=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}=-\frac{1-(-1)^{n}}{1-(-1)}=\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{2}$$
for $n=100$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100}(-1)^k=\frac{(-1)^{100}-1}{2}=\frac{1-1}{2}=0$$

Comment: How do you do to transform the third part of the first line into the fourth one?

Comment: This is of course the hard way.

Comment: you can see my edit!